Multiple VLANs on a single interface and isolation
The issue I am facing is as follows:
I have a (hypothetical) switch in Physical Location 1, and another in Physical Location 2.
Physical Location 1 switch is connected to ISP (1gbe), nearby server A (1gbe) and the switch in Physical Location 2 (10gbe).
Physical Location 2 switch is connected to nearby server B (1gbe), nearby server C (1gbe) and the switch in Physical Location 1 (10gbe).
Switch 1 - Switch 2 connection is single Cat 6A copper.
What I want to achieve is that:

Server A and B must be able to access WAN
Server A must be able to access server C
Server B must not be able to access server C
Server C must be isolated from WAN

My initial idea to solve this obviously was based on setting up VLANs and routing between them - this would require both switches to be L3 switches, right?
So, how exactly would the configuration look like? This is my initial idea, but I lack the experience to validate it:

Switch 1 Interface 1 (VLAN 10) <-> Server A
Switch 1 Interface 2 (VLAN 20) <-> ISP Router
Switch 1 Interface 3 (VLAN 10,20,30) <-> Switch 2 Interface 1 (VLAN 10,20,30)
Switch 2 Interface 2 (VLAN 20) <-> Server B
Switch 2 Interface 3 (VLAN 30) <-> Server C
Routing on Switch 1: VLAN 10 <-> VLAN 20
Routing on Switch 1: VLAN 30 <-> VLAN 10

However, this doesn't solve the issue, as Server C isn't isolated from WAN, and I'm not sure if many VLANs are possible on a single interface. I would appreciate any guidance in this matter.

managed switches do allow multiple VLAN's on a port

For simple problems there is usually a 1-to-1 mapping between a configuration that uses managed switches/VLAN's and a "dumb" configuration that does the same thing, but with more dumb switches, extra wiring and routers to move packets between the LANs.
This is useful because you can ask the question: How would I solve this problem the "dumb" way.

Missing Requirements
You don't define if Servers A and B should allow incoming connections from the internet or just have outbound connectivity. I am going to assume you have a firewall and that the firewall is NAT'ing your external IP range to a private address. Hence allowing incoming connections is just a configuration setting to forward a port on the firewall.
Config 1 - Very Simple
Dumb Version
WAN - Firewall
      |  |  |
      A  B  C

If your firewall had 4 ports, for the ISP + one connection direct to each server. You could provide a different internal IP range on each of the 3 internal ports.
The firewall is configured to:

Route + NAT from A to WAN
Route + NAT from B to WAN
Route between A and C

VLAN Version
WAN - Firewall - Switch1 - Switch2
                    |       |   |
                    A       B   C

The ports on the firewall become VLANs: A - 10, B - 20, C - 30
The connection from Firewall to Switch1 and Switch1 to Switch2 are tagged/trunked. The other ports on the switches are all on single VLANs.
Other than changing the firewall to use a trunked connection the firewall configuration remains unchanged:

Route + NAT from VLAN-10 to WAN
Route + NAT from VLAN-20 to WAN
Route between VLAN-10 and VLAN-30

Given your specific requirements the only downside to this configuration is that traffic between A and C needs to pass through the firewall.
Config 2 - Direct Routing
Dumb Version
WAN - Firewall - Router
         |        |  |
         B        A  C

We have a problem because outbound packets from A need to be routed differently based on whether they are going to the WAN or C. Hence we now need 4 internal IP ranges, one for each of A, B and C and one for communication between the firewall and the router.
The router simple routes to the target destination (A, C or WAN).
The firewall drops any packets from C since they should not go to the WAN.
VLAN Version
WAN - Firewall - Switch1 - Switch2
                    |       |   |
                    A       B   C

This is the same physical layout as before. However Switch1 is going to assume the role of the router from the dumb configuration. Therefore we need a new VLAN (40) for the communication between the Firewall and the "virtual router" actually serviced by Switch1.
The firewall is configured to:

Route + NAT from VLAN-40 to WAN - A's traffic (Note the change to 40 here)
Route + NAT from VLAN-20 to WAN - B's traffic

Switch1 is configured to route between:

VLAN-10 and VLAN-40   - A's internet traffic
VLAN-10 and VLAN-30   - Connection between A and C

Note: Even though Switch1 is "smart" it may not be flexible enough to do this precise configuration, hence you might find that Switch1 is also routing between VLAN-30 and VLAN-40 - this shouldn't be a problem because the firewall can be configured to drop this traffic (the same as the dumb config).
